# Can this problem have solutions for $N>3$:Find three $(N=3)$ positive integers a, b and c such that: $a+b+c=k^2$, $a+b=t^2$, $b+c=m^2$ and $a+c=n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can this question have solutions for N>3:

Find three ($N =3$) positive integers a, b and c such that: $a+b+c=k^2$, $a+b=x^2$, $b+c=m^2$ and $a+c=n^2$; $x, m, n∈\mathbb   N$

Solution:

Let $a+b+c=(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$

If $a+b=x^2$ then third number $c=2x+1$.

If $b+c=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1=m^2$ then :

$a=4x$, so $b=x^2-4x$

Now due to statement we must have $a+c=6x+1=n^2$

$n^2=6x+1$ can have infinite solutions such as:

$(x, n^2)=(20, 121=11^2), (60, 361=19^2), (140, 841=29^2)\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Which give:

$(a, b, c, k)=(80, 320, 41, 21), (240, 3360, 121, 61), (560, 19040, 281, 141),\cdot\cdot\cdot$

I tried to solve this problem for $N=4$, four numbers but no success. Now I have two questions:

1-Does this problem have solutions for N>3?

2-Any idea for better method?

Comment: What is the case for $N=4$ though? Are $a+b+c+d=k^2, a+b=x^2, b+c = m^2, c+d=n^2, d+a = y^2$ the only constraints?

Comment: Then $k = 65, x = 39, n = 52, m = 25, y = 60$ with $(a,b,c,d) = (a, 39^2-a, a - 39^2+25^2, 60^2 -a)$ is a solution by considering Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Specifically, do you want the cyclic sums to be square or the pairwise sums to be square? The former has 5 equations while the latter has 7 for the case $N=4$.

Comment: @player3236, I want pairwise to be square, also the sum of all numbers. N=3 in my example . I want to see if there are four or five or....numbers with this specification.

Comment: It is simply unfortunate that the case for 3 numbers do not demonstrate whether the sums are cyclic or pairwise. ($\binom 3 2=3$) Thanks for the clarification. The pairwise case seems much more interesting.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1172008_combinations_of_numbers_in_squares  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1055253_the_system_of_equations_15  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1052122_the_system_of_diophantine_equations

Comment: Update: I found this exact problem mentioned in Richard Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, section D15: Numbers whose sums in pairs make squares. Apparently Erdos and Leo Moser asked this as well, and the smallest positive solution for $N=5$ is $(7442, 28658,148583,1773458, 763442)$. A parametric solution for $N=5$ was found by Jean Lagrange, and apparently mentioned in their paper *Cinq nombres dont les sommes deux a deux sont des carres*. This should give an insight to the difficulty of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for the case $N=4$. I fail to see how this method could help resolve the cases for larger $N$.

Consider the equations

$$a + b = u^2, c + d = v^2$$
$$a + c = w^2, b + d = x^2$$
$$a + d = y^2, b + c = z^2$$
$$a + b + c + d = k^2$$

Now the first three pairs of equations give

$$u^2 + v^2 = w^2 + x^2 = y^2 + z^2 = k^2$$

so a reasonable approach would be to investigate Pythagorean triples.

Not all Pythagorean triples generate positive integers solutions, but a solution could be generated if the pairs $(u,v), (w,x), (y,z)$ are "reasonably close". Consider

$$165^2+280^2 = 195^2+260^2 = 253^2+204^2 = 325^2$$

Take note of the parity as well (or multiply it by $2$ so you don't need to worry about it)

Solving the equations give

$$a = 11817, b = 15408, c = 26208, d = 52192$$

and more solutions can be generated this way.

Comment: great job. Waiting for a general algorithm, algebraic if possible.

Comment: Solutions can be written as follows. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1157407_overall_look_for_long_equations   $p,s$− Think of it as A Pythagorean triple. And then do the conversion..... maybe something will happen.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by "@ player3236" has $k=325$.

The integer $325$ can be written as sum of two squares

in three way's & is shown below:

$k= x_1^2+x_2^2=x_3^2+x_4^2=x_5^2+x_6^2$

($x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$)=$(15,10,17,6,18,1)$

$325= 15^2+10^2=17^2+6^2=18^2+1^2$

Above can help in arriving at a parametric solution.

Also mathematician "Seiji Tomita has given parametric

solution in which $(a,b,c,d)$ taken two at a time is a

square & the link is given below.

http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph115e.html

And click on (dioph115e)

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$a + b = u^2$, $c + d = v^2$

$a + c = w^2, b + d = x^2$

$a + d = y^2, b + c = z^2$

$a + b + c + d = k^2$

Let:

$u=m^2-n^2$ & $v =2mn$

$w=p^2-q^2$ & $x=2pq$

$y=r^2-s^2$ & $z=2rs$

We apply the condition:

$m^2+n^2=p^2+q^2=r^2+s^2=k^2$

Hence, $u^2+v^2=w^2+x^2=y^2+z^2=k^2$

Since:

$2a=u^2+w^2-z^2$

$2b=x^2+z^2-v^2$

$2c=v^2+w^2-y^2$

$2d=v^2+x^2-z^2$

Substituting value of $(u,v,w,x,y,z)$ from above we get:

$a=1/2(m^4+n^4+p^4+q^4)-(m^2n^2+p^2q^2+2r^2s^2)$

$b=2(p^2q^2+r^2s^2-m^2n^2)$

$c=1/2(p^4+q^4-r^4-s^4)+(2m^2n^2-p^2q^2+r^2s^2)$

$d=2(m^2n^2+p^2q^2-r^2s^2)$

For: $(m,n,p,q,r,s,k)=(15,10,17,6,18,1,325)$ we get:

$(a,b,c,d)=(39169,-23544,24840,65160)$